# Make social media icon boxes into links

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to wrap my social media boxes with links to the corresponding link, which is a custom field called from my WordPress event plugin. If you visit any event page (e.g. http://familyoffestivals.com/event/hangout-music-festival-2014/) and scroll to the "Popular Links" section, you can see the social media boxes I'm referring to.

The "Popular Links" icons are fontawesome.

```
<div class=”instagram-fourth”>
<p style=”float: center;”><span style=”color: #3f729b;”><i class=”fa fa-instagram fa-5x”></i></span></p>
<?php echo tribe_get_custom_field(‘Instagram’); ?>
</div>
```

I asked the event developer (https://tri.be/support/forums/topic/make-a-link-using-tribe_get_custom_fieldcustom-field-here/) and they weren't much help.

Let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

So the field of Instagram hosts the instagram url for that event or event host?

Could you use something like this then?

```
<a href="<?php echo tribe_get_custom_field('Instagram'); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-5x"></i></a>
```

I'm assuming that i class holds your Instagram icon in it.

Or does the custom field hold the icon and the link?

If so then you'll probably have to break it up into Instagram_Logo and Instagram_URL and then do something like this.

```
<a href="<?php echo tribe_get_custom_field('Instagram_URL'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo tribe_get_custom_field('Instagram_Icon') ;?></a>
```